# Can't find intellij register button

Tags: intellij-idea

I may be being blind or stupid, but I can't find the register button in the help menu.
I've made a new project and I am looking in the right place, at least I think so.

{Edit}

To clarify, since I can't upload screenshots, the options I have are:

- find action
- Help topics
- Tip of the Day
- Productivity Guide
- Contact Support Team
- Submit Feedback
- Configure Debug Log Settings
- Show log in Explorer
- Online Documentation
- What's new in IntelliJIDEA
- Default Keymap References
- JetBrains TV
- Check for Update...
- About

Comment: err ... help --> register?

Comment: Maybe you're using Community edition?

Comment: Ahh, that's probably it,I've been using it for a while. Like I said, It's me being stupid